# Error in parse XML: NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 111

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I'm using the following way to parse XML:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xml];
[parser parse];
```

And got following error 
Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=111 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 111.)"

I tried to find the meaning of code 111, but actually there's nothing in apple's document about NSXMLParser (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

The xml data is show as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WPPacket Type="ACKDATA">
<TableEnquiry Code="4"/>
</WPPacket>
```

Thanks

Comment: show your definition part for 'xml'

Comment: @manujmv, finally, i found it's the data format issue: ANSII and utf-8